# Detect whether code is being run in the context of migrate/makemigrations command

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, django-1.8

I have a model with dynamic choices, and I would like to return an empty choice list if I can guarantee that the code is being run in the event of a `django-admin.py migrate / makemigrations` command to prevent it either creating or warning about useless choice changes.

Code:

```
from artist.models import Performance
from location.models import Location

def lazy_discover_foreign_id_choices():
    choices = []

    performances = Performance.objects.all()
    choices += {performance.id: str(performance) for performance in performances}.items()

    locations = Location.objects.all()
    choices += {location.id: str(location) for location in locations}.items()

    return choices
lazy_discover_foreign_id_choices = lazy(lazy_discover_foreign_id_choices, list)


class DiscoverEntry(Model):
    foreign_id = models.PositiveIntegerField('Foreign Reference', choices=lazy_discover_foreign_id_choices(), )
```

So I would think if I can detect the run context in `lazy_discover_foreign_id_choices` then I can choose to output an empty choice list. I was thinking about testing `sys.argv` and `__main__.__name__` but I'm hoping there's possibly a more reliable way or an API?

Comment: How exactly are your choices dynamic? Could you post some code?

Comment: Sure thing, code added

Comment: How do you import `Performance` and `Location`?

Comment: Updated code to show imports.

Comment: For me there is another problem: those are not _historical_ versions of these models. This might cause unexpected behavior in migrations, because those models you import are the newest versions, while in migrations, you get the current migration versions.

Comment: @Ivan That won't be a problem when an empty list is returned during makemigrations :)

Comment: @Ivan that sounds complex, and fun! I'll give it a whirl if there's no other silver bullet answers

Comment: @Ivan it is the `makemigrations` phase that is important here, the migration phase only executes the migration files created during it.

Comment: @aumo Actually I would like it to apply to `migrate` command as well to avoid the warning that migrate will generate when it detects that `makemigrations` is needed. In that sense, I guess subclassing the migrate command as per your answer would also suffice.

Comment: Indeed that would be enough

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution I can think of would be to subclass the Django `makemigrations` command to set a flag before actually performing the actual operation.

**Example:**

Put that code in `<someapp>/management/commands/makemigrations.py`, it will override Django's default `makemigrations` command.

```
from django.core.management.commands import makemigrations
from django.db import migrations


class Command(makemigrations.Command):
    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Set the flag.
        migrations.MIGRATION_OPERATION_IN_PROGRESS = True

        # Execute the normal behaviour.
        super(Command, self).handle(*args, **kwargs)
```

Do the same for the `migrate` command.

And modify your dynamic choices function:

```
from django.db import migrations


def lazy_discover_foreign_id_choices():
    if getattr(migrations, 'MIGRATION_OPERATION_IN_PROGRESS', False):
        return []
    # Leave the rest as is.
```

It is very hacky but fairly easy to setup.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't work. Seems that the model field choices is executes before `Command.handle()`

Comment: I tried it on a project of mine and it seemed to work, I'll investigate.

Comment: @DanH I confirm that it works fine on a clean install of Django 1.8.5, are you sure that it is the new command that gets executed and not the default one?

Comment: Sorry you're right, it is working for `makemigrations`. However the same concept does not seem to be working for `migrate` command.

Comment: The problem with `migrate` being that `Command.handle()` executes too late if I put an exception in both `migrate.Command.handle()` and `lazy_discover_foreign_id_choices()`. Not sure if this is a conclusive test though?

Comment: No, it is normal that `lazy_discover_foreign_id_choices ` gets executed before, it will be re-executed after, try printing some text instead of raising an exception, you will see. Are you checking the right flag for the `migrate` command? You should either check both flags in `lazy_discover_foreign_id_choices` or setting the flag elsewhere.

Comment: For some reason I'm seeing success on both commands since your edit to use `migrations.MIGRATION_OPERATION_IN_PROGRESS`. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Here is a fairly non hacky way to do this (since django already creates flags for us) :

```
import sys
def lazy_discover_foreign_id_choices():
    if ('makemigrations' in sys.argv or 'migrate' in sys.argv):
        return []
    # Leave the rest as is.
```

This should work for all cases.

Comment: Oh, this is a really nice way to do this.

Comment: Wow, I just come with the same idea! It is a really simple though working approach.

Comment: Any way to isolate the migration phase of testing?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`django.db.models.signals.pre_migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#pre-migrate) should be enough to detect the `migrate` command. The drawback is that you cannot use it at configuration stage.